# How can I use LightDM for user-defined sessions?

Tags: lightdm

If I unterstand it correctly, LightDM has replaced GDM per default. I wonder if it's possible to make it run the things I put in my .xinitrc file ... what I need is an option below "Unity" and "Unity 2D" which says "Run a user-defined session".

Is that possible? Should be the easiest thing, but I did not get a clue so far. I export and define and run a lot of things in this file, so it's pretty important for me to have control over that.

What I do NOT want is a custom session in /usr/some/where, I only want it to run the stuff from each user's xinitrc (or similar).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a new file `/usr/share/xsessions/custom.desktop` with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Xsession
Exec=/etc/X11/Xsession
```

You should now have a new session option during login, Xsession will load the user's `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: Ubuntu only considers ~/.xsession or maybe ~/.xsessionrc and ~/.Xsession now (12.04)

Comment: Does one need to restart X, or simply logout, for this to take effect?

Answer (score 7):

Create a new file `/usr/share/xsessions/default.desktop` (The name is up to you, but it has to have `.desktop` suffix):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Default
Comment=This runs user session and logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=default
Icon=
```

Now when you select this session in `lightdm` and log in, your `~/.xsession` file, if exists, will be executed.

Note that the user's file that is executed is `~/.xsession`, and not `~/.xinitrc`, which was mentioned in the question. (`~/.xinitrc` is used when the X session is started using the `startx` script from a command line.)

Some explanations:
The `Name` entry is what `lightdm` would display for this session. The `Exec` entry is the important thing, and it should be the name of the program that starts the actual session. When you log in, `lightdm` calls the `/etc/X11/Xsession` script, passing it the value of `Exec` as an argument, and `Xsession` will, eventually, execute this program (for example, it could be `startxfce4` for starting a `xfce4` session).
If the `Exec` entry is the special string `default`, then `Xsession` will execute the user's `~/.xsession` file. (`Xsession` would also execute `~/.xsession` if it's called without aruments.)

Sorry, I'm new here and hence cannot comment on other people's answers, but I'd like to comment on the accepted answer, to make things clearer. As per my explanation above, what will happen with that answer's method is that `Xsession` would be called by `lightdm` with an argument which is (the full path of) `Xsession`. So `Xession` will run and then call itself, this time with no arguments. The second `Xsession`, being called with no arguments, will execute the user's `~/.xsession`. So the desired action will, eventually, be taken, but in a bit awkward way.

Comment: Typo: /user -> /usr (cannot edit as edits must be at least six chars long, LOL).

Answer (score 1):

To use olvwm:

1) Type `sudo apt-get install olvwm` in a console

2) Create this session :

```
/usr/share/xsessions/olvwm.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Open Look
Exec=olvwm
Type=Application
```