# Unity does not run .xsession/.Xsession/.xsessionrc/.xinitrc on login

Tags: unity, xorg, unity-2d

I recently moved from Fedora 14 to Ubuntu 12.04 and in the past, I disabled my touchpad and configured my trackpoint settings with .xsession, which would execute on login.

Now, with Ubuntu 12.04, I cannot get that file to execute at login. I've tried renaming it to `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsessionrc`, `~/.xsession`, and `~/.Xsession`, but none of these are executed.

I've tried with both Unity2d and Unity3d.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: The answer is here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/77191/how-can-i-use-lightdm-for-user-defined-sessions