# remote desktop connection ubuntu with kde as desktop enviroment

Tags: 20.04, kde

I have my windows pc that I use regularly and an ubuntu 20.04 machine, when I installed ubuntu I changed the desktop environment to KDE plasma following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMNbPH1s31M&ab_channel=MTSoftware). my ubuntu machine is working great with KDE, but my issue came when I tried to use remote desktop connection in my windows machine to connect to the Ubuntu one, when i do it (i successfully connect to it) I log in the gnome environment, and not the KDE. is there an easy solution or something I should change? I did not see any option to choose which environment to use at any time...

any help for a linux newbe?

Comment: It seems like you changed your default desktop environment for a set of users (or groups), yet not for the remina / rdp services, and will have to change it manually, maybe [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172314/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-to-a-specific-desktop-environment) will help. **do not delete your gnome DE** unless you are sure absolutely sure you won't affect any other services. Maybe also consider installing Kubuntu instead?