# How can I remove the "GNOME desktop environment" entry from my login screen after uninstalling GNOME?

Tags: gnome, lightdm, session

I installed `The GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components`, but I didn't like it, so I uninstalled it. *But now at the login screen, besides the password box there's still the button to choose Unity, Gnome and Gnome basic or something like that. How can I completely remove it?*

Comment: @MHC, thanks for the edit. I didn't do anything other than the italics because there recently were questions raised about editing questions to fit the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere that (sudo) deleting what you don't need from `/usr/share/xsessions` will clean up your login screen. While the titles of the `.desktop` files are quite explanatory, you could make sure by viewing their contents in a text editor. Just to be safe, copy those `.desktop` files elsewhere first!

See [How can I use LightDM for user-defined sessions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/77191/25656) for more.

Comment: Found this after searching for `lightdm still showing session after removing desktop file from /usr/share/xsessions`. In my case, I was on Fedora 38 Cinnamon and had installed the 'Fedora Workstation' (Gnome) group then decided to get rid of it. removing the desktop file from `/usr/share/xsessions` was only part of the solution for me. After some investigating, I realized there was also a `/usr/bin/gnome-session` and package `gnome-session`; removing that got rid of the remaining entries. I am not sure what the ubuntu equivalent is but maybe this can point someone in the right direction.