# LightDM causing display issues with i3

Tags: nvidia, xorg, lightdm, i3-wm, xinit

So I have just done an Ubuntu minimal install with i3, here are the steps I have taken so far:

- On boot `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1` to get access to terminal
- Login using details provided during setup
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common git`
- `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:system76-dev/stable`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install system76-driver system76-driver-nvidia`
- `sudo apt-get install i3`
- `sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/95-i3.conf`
- Add code block below and `CTRL` + `x`
- `sudo reboot`

LightDM i3 conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=i3
```

Now if I log in using LightDM I get the following screen:

[image: LightDM Desktop]

Which is zoomed out (tiny status line fonts) and has odd red/green/blue pixels at the top of the screen (this changes with every boot sometimes the screen is all white with lots of colored blocks of pixels).

Now if install `xinit` and create a `~/.xinitrc` with the following code:

```
exec i3
```

I can then reboot and run `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1` from the LightDM login to access a terminal and run `startx` this then renders with the following screen:

[image: startx Desktop]

This has resolved the above issues there are no colored squares and the status line fonts are a proper size.

When running `nvidia-settings` on both the card seems to be working fine so I do not think it is a nVidia issue.

From what I can tell there is a difference in how LightDM and `startx` kick things off and what ever that difference is seems to be causing bugs, this is the first time I have really dug deep with nVidia and Xorg on Ubuntu so I am hoping someone has come across something like this before.

I am aware I could just run `startx` but I would like to be able to resolve this issue and use LightDM as I find it a nicer *flow*.

[UPDATE]

After doing more research I think this issue may be due to LightDM's custom [Xsession](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/Xsession.5.html) I am now attempting to set up a [Custom Xsession](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession).

[UPDATE 2]

Removing `95-i3.conf` and updating `i3.desktop` to `Exec=Default` and creating a `.xsession` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec i3
```

Has not made any difference (based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77191/how-can-i-use-lightdm-for-user-defined-sessions)).